# Who is responsible for cleanup?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, system, callstack

I wish to know which one is responsible for cleanup of the stack

Suppose you have a function fun lets say like this:

```
var = fun(int x, int y, float z, char x);
```

when `fun` will get called it will go into the stack along with the parameters then when the function returns who is responsible for cleanup of the stack is it the function it self or the "var" which will hold the return value.

One more thing, can anyone explain the concepts of calling conventions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) refers to who is doing the cleanup of the stack; caller or callee.

> Calling conventions can differ in:
>
> - where parameters and return values are placed (in registers; on the call
>     stack; a mix of both)
> - the order in which parameters are passed (or parts of a single
>     parameter)
> - how the task of setting up and cleaning up a function call is divided
>     between the caller and the callee.
> - which registers that may be directly used by the callee may sometimes also
>     be included
>
> Architectures almost always have more
>   than one possible calling convention.

Answer (score 10):

You referred to the answer yourself: **calling conventions**.

A calling convention is similar to a **contract**. It decides the following things:

- Who is responsible to cleanup the parameters.
- How and in which order the parameters are passed to the called function.
- Where the return value is stored.

There are many different calling conventions, depending on the platform and the programming environment. Two common calling conventions on the x86 platforms are:

> **stdcall**
>
> The parameters are passed onto the stack from right to left. The *called* function cleans up the stack.
>
> **cdecl**
>
> The parameters are passed onto the stack from right to left. The *calling* function cleans up the stack.

In both cases the return value is in the `EAX` register (or `ST0` for floating point values)

Many programming languages for the x86 platform allow to specify the calling convention, for example:

> **Delphi**
>
> ```
> function MyFunc(x: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
> ```
>
> **Microsoft C/C++**
>
> ```
> int __stdcall myFunc(int x)
> ```

**Some usage notes:**

When creating a simple application it's rarely necessary to change or to know about the calling convention, but there are two typical cases where you need to concern yourself with calling conventions:

- When calling external libraries, Win32 API for example: You have to use compatible calling conventions, otherwise the stack might get corrupted.
- When creating inline assembler code: You have to know in which registers and where on the stack you find the variables.

For further details I recommend these Wikipedia articles:

- [Calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)
- [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Answer (score 0):

By the time that line is complete var will hold the value returned by fun() and any memory on the stack used by fun will be gone: "push", "pop" all tidy.

Calling conventions: everything that the compiler organises so that fun can do its work. Consider those parameters x, y, z. What order do they get pushed onto the stack (indeed do they get passed via the stack)? Doesn't matter so long as the caller and callee agree! It's a convention.